# Azure Devops nested YAML tasks doesn't get cancelled even after cancelling the pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

Azure Devops nested YAML tasks doesn't get cancelled even after cancelling the pipeline, restarting the agent.

At the top left, pipeline is cancelled but jobs are still running

[image]